# Type mismatch problem VBA - Formula to Value

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

I have a range which first I populate with formula then I am trying to convert it to a value, and then I use sumifs the range based on criterias. However, I get

> Type Mismatch error

in the line where I use Sumifs. I suppose that my mistake comes from changing the value from formula to value. However, I cannot use Select, Copy, PasteSpecial since I have more tha 2084 rows. I have been struggling for quite some time. Any suggestions?

```
Dim DWR, MHR, P, D As Worksheet

Set DWR = Sheets("DWREP")
Set MHR = Sheets("MACH-HRS")
Set P = Sheets("PRODUCTION")
Set D = Sheets("DELAYS")
Dim planned_time, tech_time, lost_time, std_time As Long

Dim last_row, last_row1, last_row2 As Long
last_row = MHR.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
last_row1 = P.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
last_row2 = D.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If P.range("CC2").Formula = "" Then
    P.range("CC2").FormulaR1C1 = "=PRODUCTION!RC[-66]/VLOOKUP(PRODUCTION!RC[-76],STD!R3C1:R1030C17,17,FALSE)"

P.range("CC2").AutoFill Destination:=P.range("CC2:CC" & last_row1), Type:=4
P.range("CC2:CC" & last_row1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
With P
    With .range("CC2" & last_row1)
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
End If
std_time = Application.SumIfs(P.range("CC2:CC" & last_row1), P.range("A2:A" & last_row1), DWR.Cells(7, i), P.range("C2:C" & last_row1), DWR.range("B31"))
```

Comment: Where are you defining `i`?  Also, note that `DWR`, `MHR`, `P`, `planned_time`, `tech_time` and `lost_time` are all `Variant`s - only `std_time` is a `Long` and `D` is a `Worksheet`.  `Dim DWR As Worksheet, MHR As Worksheet, P As Worksheet, D As Worksheet: Dim planned_time As Long, tech_time As Long, lost_time As Long, std_time As Long`

Comment: `i` is just to iterate through the columns. Those that you mentioned, I have used in separate sumifs with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the column on your `With` block.

Change:
`.range("CC2" & last_row1)`

For:
`.range("CC2:CC" & last_row1)`

Comment: Correct! But still I get the same error on the line with the Sumifs function....

Comment: @LBD_23 Try using `Debug.Print` with your `SumIfs` - if it is returning an Error code (e.g. `#VALUE!`) then you can't store it in a `Long`